# How to take an NSInteger from one .h or .m file to another .h or .m file?

Tags: ios4

I want to have a quiz that will display the score at the end. But since it is in a different pair of .h and .m files, how would I bring it over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a vague question, but the keyword *extern* jumps to mind. It allows files to share variables.

ScoreGiver controls the score like.
ScoreNeeder uses the same score.

**ScoreGiver.h:**

```
int score;
void incrementScore();
```

**ScoreGiver.m:**

```
#import "ScoreGiver.h"

int score = 0;

void incrementScore() {
    score++;
}
```

**ScoreNeeder.h:**

```
extern int score;
void logScore();
```

**ScoreNeeder.m:**

```
#import "ScoreNeeder.h"

void logScore() {
    NSLog(@"This score is now: %d", score);
}
```

**main.m:**

```
#import "ScoreNeeder.h"
#import "ScoreGiver.h"

/*********OUTPUT************
 The score is now: 0
 The score is now: 1
 The score is now: 3
 ***************************/
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    logScore();
    incrementScore();
    logScore();
    incrementScore();
    incrementScore();
    logScore();
}
```

**NB:** It's not good programming practice to use global variables like this, especially in an object oriented language.

Comment: Okay, this worked. But now I have another question and I feel that it is too closely related to this one to have another post. How would I have a button change the text of a label on the view that the button will also bring up?

Comment: That's a little bit more complicated. Working through the [Cocoa Application Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/01Introduction/01Introduction.html) and [iPhone Application Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Creating_an_iPhone_App/index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007595) helped me. Also hit that response with a Green Check mark if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the code file that will be receiving the integer, create a property and method signature like so:

```
@interface FinalViewController : UIViewController{
    NSInteger finalScore;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSInteger finalScore;

-(void)setFinalScore:(NSInteger)num;
@end
```

And the method should look like this:

```
-(void)setFinalScore:(NSInteger)num{
self.finalScore = num;
}
```

Then, the part where you instantiate the view controller from the original view should look something like:

```
FinalViewController *finalView = [[FinalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FinalView" 
                                                                       bundle:nil];

[finalView setFinalScore:score]

[view addSubview:finalView.view];
```

Comment: this doesn't make sense. I want to bring the nsingeter from one .m file to another.

Comment: Yeah, you're creating an instance of the class and then passing it the object. This should work for you. Just read it again and give it a shot...